# Why I can not set onClickListener for a button in a dialog view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-manifest

I have a custom dialog which described below.

My Custom Dialog layout (***my_dialog.xml***) which only contain a "dismiss" button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

     >

         <Button
            android:id="@+id/dismiss_btn"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Dismiss me"
            android:textSize="8dip"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
             />
     </RelativeLayout>
```

my dialog view class:

```
 public class MyDialog extends Dialog{

        public MyDialog(Context context){
            super(context);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.my_dialog);

                 Button dismissMeBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.dismiss_btn);

                /** ERROR Message when set onClickListener below (throw by eclipse editor)**/

               //     The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the 
                //    type View is not applicable for the arguments (new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){})

                dismissMeBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                         MyDialog.this.dismiss(); 
                    }
                  });

            getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        }


    }
```

As the code indicated above, I have a "***dismiss_btn***" button on the dialog, I would like to dismiss the dialog when the dismiss button is pressed, but I got an error in my code when ***setOnClickListener*** for the dismiss button (as indicated in the code).

Error message (error throw by eclipse editor):

**The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the   type View is not applicable  for the arguments (new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){})**

Why I got the error? Why I can not set onClickListener for a button in a dialog view?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As eclipse thinks it is DialogInterface onClickListener but you need a View onClickListener so it will be

```
                dismissMeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     MyDialog.this.dismiss(); 
                }
              });
```

Comment: Needed to use this approach to implement a 'Fragment Pager' example: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html. Hope it helps someone out there!

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are in the context of `DialogInterface` and it has `OnClickListener` interface on its own.

Your code should be:

```
dismissMeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         MyDialog.this.dismiss(); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a problem with your imports.
When you try to create a new OnClickListener, you are invoking the constructor of DialogInterface.OnClickListener, which is not the needed OnClickListener for a Button (probably due to an `import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener` )

Try to use `new View.OnclickListener(){ ... }` or replace the import by `import android.view.View.OnClickListener` and it should be alritght.