# warning The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnClickListener(){})

Tags: onclicklistener

```
package com.example.andrappexp1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
  ......;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Button button;//set a variable

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //diaplay the Main_activity
    button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);//find the button1;

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { ///<----here is warning.
    @Override
    public void onclick(View source) { ///and here. see bellow,
        //System.out.println("show on the screen"); 
        TextView show=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.button1);  
        show.setText("hit"); 
        }
    }
})
```

The method onclick(View) of type new OnClickListener(){} must override or implement a supertype method

Comment: this might be help full http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612229/why-i-can-not-set-onclicklistener-for-a-button-in-a-dialog-view#answer-6612327

Answer (score 0):

Please try to properly format your question and make sure you are really asking a question ([FAQ: How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)). Additionally you should search for similar questions/problems before posting....

It looks like you imported the wrong `OnClickListener`. You need to import `View.OnClickListener`.

Either change your import or do it like that:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override
    public void onclick(View source) { 
        //System.out.println("show on the screen"); 
        TextView show=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.button1);  
        show.setText("hit"); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have that, like this import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
     import android.widget.TextView;

Comment: I find there was a similar title at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606662/onclicklistener-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-and-not-applicable/20068848#20068848
I try those code but still get warning.

Comment: warning, the type new View.OnClickListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method View.OnClickListener.onClick(View) at (new View.OnClickListen() ...);  when I add View. ahead of OnClick...

Comment: Then you probably have done it wrong. You can update you initial question with the updated code to make it more clear what you tried.

Comment: unwichtich, despite I have solved the question, but I still edit it to fit the fomat to show others. I try to vote your answer, but I was warned I have to have 15reps at least. so sorry for not vote.

Comment: Others can use @, but when I use it, it disappears, odd enough.